# F# List (Seq.toList) to Json

Tags: .net, json, f#, dataprovider

I am pretty new to F# so this might be a dumb question. I am using an Excel data provider to parse an excel and then convert it to JSON, so far I mamaged to get the data from excel to a list (`let rows = file.Data |> Seq.toList`)
However I am not sure on how to get it to generate a JSON that I would later expose as an API.
The list shows in this format:

> [Row 1
>       Approval Date = Jul-25 2017 03:14PM 
>    Assigned
>   Group = XXXXXXXXXXXXX 
>    Assigned User = ZZZZZZ 
>     Available
>   Date = Jul-25 2017 03:14PM 
>   Building = XXXXX 
>   Bundle =
>   Global Common - XXXXXXTZZZZ 
>      Checker Due Date =  
>    City =
>   San Antonio
>
> Row 2 
>     Approval Date = Jul-25 2017 03:14PM 
>    Assigned
>   Group = XXXXXXXXXXXXX 
>    Assigned User = ZZZZZZ 
>     Available
>   Date = Jul-25 2017 03:14PM 
>   Building = XXXXX 
>   Bundle =
>   XXXXXXXXXXXX 
>     Checker Due Date = 
>     City = New York 
>   ...]

I just need to generate a JSON from this.
Thanks a million in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a library for it the most comon one as far as I know is https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Just Reference it on your project then you can call it with.

```
let json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject obj
```

Comment: Many Thanks, I already figured out, but I used a different serializer